# Column of buffer position in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

In Emacs Lisp, if you have a buffer position stored in a variable, how do you find what column it is in?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out documentation for [columns](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Columns.html) and for [`save-excursion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/save_002dexcursion.html).

```
(save-excursion (goto-char pos) (current-column))
```

Comment: I'm curious why there is no `column-number-at-pos` function using this corresponding with `line-number-at-pos`?

Answer (score 1):

Trey already nailed it (though I haven't personally tried it), but here is something that I wrote to do it.

```
(defun calculate-column (point)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char point)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (- point (point))))
```

Comment: When there is a build-in function `current-column`, why bother calculating it yourself? You're just going to forget all the special cases. Like tabs.

Comment: @nschum Or like `'display` properties.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ambiguity in the question: "what column is it in" could mean either 1) "what character column does it appear to be in" or 2) "how many characters does one have to advance from the beginning of the line to get to the current position".  These are normally the same, but can be different in the presence of characters with a text property like '(display (space :width 7)) [which says to display the characters having that text property as if they were 7 spaces wide].

The elisp function current-column returns meaning 1 but computing on values of (point) returns meaning 2. Trey Jackson's answer will return a different value than compman's because of this in some circumstances.

Another possibility for meaning 2 is (- (point) (line-beginning-position))